# Scala and 'different type of instance of trait Map: java.util.Map[K,V]'

Tags: scala

I am getting the above mentioned Error from Scala compiler.

I am quite new to Scala and experimenting with it by converting a Java project that I have, to Scala. In my Java project, I am using Apache 'commons-chain' and I have a class that is extending 'org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ContextBase' and I am getting this error for it. I searched the internet it seems this problem has something to do with type erasure but my class doesn't not do anything special, just inherits from this class.

`class SpecialContext extends ContextBase {
}`

and here is the exact error I get..

`Error:(10, 7) illegal inheritance;
 class SpecialContext inherits different type instances of trait Map:
java.util.Map[K,V] and java.util.Map[K,V]
class SpecialContext extends ContextBase {`

One of the attractions of Scala for me, while I can use nice language features of Scala, I would be still able to use the extensive number of open source libraries of the Java. After this experience, I am questioning this fact, considering my class not doing anything special, is it always this problematic to integrate the Java world and Scala world.

First my question is off-course is there a solution for the problem I described above?

Second question is, how is your experience integrating Scala and Java libraries? Or am I following the wrong way, are there ports of the popular Java libraries to Scala, like command-chain here, or lets say Spring....

Thx for answers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `ContextChain` is that it uses raw types: in https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-chain/apidocs/org/apache/commons/chain/impl/ContextBase.html you can see `Map` and `HashMap` instead of `Map<Something, Something>`.

[Java only supports raw types to integrate with old, pre-generics code (to remind you, Java 5 was released in 2004),](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) so you shouldn't see them in modern Java libraries. Scala doesn't support them at all.